# Issue in Uploading Video to Cloudinary REACT NATIVE EXPO

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to record a video from Phone and Upload to Cloudinary...

Now I have tried this code:

```
const pickImage = async () => {
let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [4, 3],
  base64: true,
});

if (!result.cancelled) {
  let base64Img = `data:image/jpg;base64,${result.base64}`;

  //Add your cloud name
  let apiUrl = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/bniaxee/image/upload";

  let data = {
    file: base64Img,
    upload_preset: "animationstudiogo",
  };

  fetch(apiUrl, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
  })
    .then(async (r) => {
      let data = await r.json();
      console.log(data.secure_url);
      return data.secure_url;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

};

This works but

This does not work if in options of ImagePicker we set
**mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,**
because it does not return Base64 and Cloudinary accepts it in Base64 format.

Now I have looked for ways to convert recorder video to base64 but it is not working... I even used this Javascript function but didn't work

```
function toDataURL(url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
```

}

Don't know what to do, Please anyone help.

**NOTE: I DON"T WANT TO EJECT FROM EXPO**

Answer (score 1):

Hey I faced the same issue uploading a video to Cloudinary using Expo and was able to get around it by first uploading it to my server (node.js) and then using the Cloudinary SDK to upload it to Cloudinary. The reason we need to upload it to the server is because there is no Cloudinary SDK for React Native yet, and this documentation on Cloudinary says that the file option specifying the file path is only available for the SDKs: [Cloudinary Required Parameters](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#required_parameters)

I also was unsuccessful converting it to base64 and in the same documentation above it says that it limits upload sizes of base64 to 60 MB so I don't think that's a good option anyway since chunking uploads is available for the SDK as well.

If first uploading it to your server and then uploading it to Cloudinary from there is a possibility, then here is a couple quick key parts:

React Native App:

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append('video-upload', {
  name: 'my-video-upload',
  type: 'video/mov',
  uri: localVideo //Refers to the video in the result of your ImagePicker
})
try {
  let response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: Util.serverUrl + '/upload-video',
    data: data,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
  })
  console.log(response.data, 'Successfully uploaded video')
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err.response.data, 'Failed uploading video')
}
```

Server:

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'name',
    api_key: 'key',
    api_secret: 'secret',
})

//

const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'api',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '_' + moment().unix() + '.mov')
    }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

//

app.post('/upload-video', upload.single('video-upload'), async (req, res, next) => {
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(__dirname + req.file.filename, {
    resource_type: 'video'
}, function (error, result) {
    console.log(error, 'This is the error')
    console.log(result, 'This is the result')
})
```

You'll need to understand multer and the Cloudinary SDK for node.js to get it working properly for you.

I can go into more detail if this way is a possibility for you. Another possible option is first uploading the video to s3, then specify that s3 location to Cloudinary as one of the file type options is an s3 bucket. I haven't tried uploading videos but there are other posts about uploading files to s3 from React Native that you could check out.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done from the frontend using FileSystem.readAsStringAsync

```
FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri, { encoding: 'base64' })
```